# Как исправить уязвимости блога

Tags: php, javascript

Написал блог, для практики. Посты добавляются в базу следующим пост запросом из javascript'a через ajax — `xhttp.send("action=addPost&theme=Тема&post=ТекстПоста");` или удаляются по id — `xhttp.send("action=deletePost&id=" + 123);` или удаляются все — `xhttp.send("action=deleteAllPosts");`

Я написал отдельно "экплоит", который шлет выше указанные запросы, посты свободно добавляются/удаляются. Как от этого защититься? Проверять реферер? И как лучше проверять? Если я не ошибаюсь, то curl'ом можно подменить и его..

Comment: @gear, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привязка к аккаунту. Отсылается же на php скрипт и возможно

```
if(USER_GROUP == "Admin"){
//выполнять код
} else {
 echo "Вы не имеете доступа к данному разделу";
}
```

P.S. С js не ахти у меня... Если что - исправляйте)

Answer (score 1):

Шта?
Во-первых, на JS не предоставлять таких кнопок и функционала (что, впрочем, никак не влияет на успешность атаки).
Во-вторых, ВСЕГДА проверять на пыхе ВСЕ действия, которые поступают от клиента!